# send and receive XML via HTTP POST method in Android (REST API)

Tags: android, rest

I am new on REST full service. I want to work with send and receive XML via HTTP POST method in android. Can anyone give me any link or step by step full procedure where I could go through step by step to do this with any simple demo example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using java or javascript?

Comment: hello, thanks for quick response. i'm using android native development with java.

Comment: @KNeerajLal please help me if you have any solution

Comment: Please check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit for making api call [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/) is the link to set up and work with retrofit with sample

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the tutorial but here they have used json data retrieve. But I want post username, password via xml and in future i also want to retrieve that data via xml. so now how can i achieve this?

Comment: same retrofit library used to retrieve xml data as well look here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter

Answer (score 0):

There are a 2 methods to call a REST API in android.

- Using [`java.net.HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). See this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android).
- Using some library like [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master) or [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Link to some popular libraries are [here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/65). Here is a [tutorial with Retrofit](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/). And here is [tutorial with Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/).

Comment: I got these links previously but it didn't help me.

Comment: So what are you looking for?